# Malibu coconut rum Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, liquor-beer

Anyone has an idea if [malibu coconut rum](http://www.maliburumdrinks.com/us/) is kosher?

Comment: Future readers should note that the status as kosher of this rum may have changed between when answers were posted below and when they're reading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rosends pointed out these links, which say:

- [Malibu Cocunut from Spain is not approved.](http://kosherliquorlist.com/en/malibu/511-malibu-coconut-1-l--8410024700008.html)
- [Malibu Cocunut from Scotland is under the Hechsher of the KLBD, even if not written on the bottle.](http://kosherliquorlist.com/en/malibu/512-malibu-coconut-75-cl--5010284100018.html)

However, I might ask a Kashrus organization directly, as [Star-K has a general "not authorized" for Malibu rum.](https://www.star-k.org/resource/list/4MLC6KC3/Rum-_Spiced_or_Flavored)

Comment: I wonder what the difference is, in Israel I have only found the Spanish one..